# HashMap key that is made up of multiple tokens and has non-null value mapping returns null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I am creating a currency exchange application from csv data and have hit a road block. I am storing the main currency exchange rate table in a LinkedHashMap of the following type:

```
LinkedHashMap[String,LinkedHashMap[String,Double]]
```

It will store the data as [Country, [Year,Rate]].

When I print to the console to confirm that the Map is being populated properly, I receive confirmation of a full `KeySet` and proper value mappings. Additionally, the application runs smoothly for any country names consisting of only one token. However, countries with more than one token in their names return null even though the map is populated with that key and its correct corresponding value.

For example, printing `getExchangeRates()` will return all K-V pairs including the following:

```
Australia={1960=0.8929, 1961=0.8929, 1962=0.8929, 1963=0.8929, 1964=0.8929, 1965=0.8929...},
Czech Republic={1990=21.145, 1991=27.92, 1992=28.37, 1993=29.153, 1994=28.785, 1995=26.541...},
New Zealand={1960=0.7143, 1961=0.7155, 1962=0.7192, 1963=0.7192, 1964=0.7192, 1965=0.7192...}
```

Printing `getExchangeRates().get("Australia")` will return the LinkedHashMap of years and rates; however, printing `getExchangeRates().get("Czech Republic")` or `getExchangeRates().get("New Zealand")` will return null.

Does anyone know why this would be happening? I am befuddled.

Code and csv snippet included for reference, but as I said, the HashMap appears to be populating correctly.

,1960,1961,1962,1963,1964,1965,1966,1967,1968,1969,1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1975,1976,1977,1978,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008
Australia,0.8929,0.8929,0.8929,0.8929,0.8929,0.8929,0.8929,0.8929,0.8929,0.8929,0.8929,0.8827,0.8387,0.7041,0.6967,0.7639,0.8183,0.9018,0.8737,0.8946,0.8782,0.8702,0.9859,1.11,1.1395,1.4319,1.496,1.4282,1.2799,1.2646,1.2811,1.2838,1.3617,1.4706,1.3678,1.349,1.2779,1.3474,1.5918,1.55,1.7248,1.9334,1.8406,1.5419,1.3598,1.3095,1.328,1.1951,1.1922
Austria,1.88949,1.88949,1.88949,1.88949,1.88949,1.88949,1.88949,1.88949,1.88949,1.88949,1.88949,1.81394,1.67985,1.42293,1.35844,1.26573,1.30373,1.20106,1.05533,0.97145,0.94024,1.15745,1.23975,1.30544,1.45412,1.50356,1.1095,0.91877,0.89734,0.96151,0.82628,0.84852,0.79862,0.84534,0.83005,0.73265,0.76936,0.88691,0.89962,0.93863,1.0854,1.11751,1.06255,0.88603,0.80537,0.80412,0.79714,0.73064,0.68268
Belgium,1.23947,1.23947,1.23947,1.23947,1.23947,1.23947,1.23947,1.23947,1.23947,1.23947,1.23947,1.21145,1.09109,0.9662,0.96558,0.91173,0.957,0.88852,0.78067,0.72679,0.72488,0.92041,1.13264,1.26752,1.43243,1.47194,1.10739,0.92549,0.91146,0.9768,0.82841,0.84651,0.79697,0.85762,0.82936,0.73079,0.76752,0.88681,0.89982,0.93863,1.0854,1.11751,1.06255,0.88603,0.80537,0.80412,0.79714,0.73064,0.68268
Canada,0.9698,1.0131,1.0701,1.0811,1.0811,1.0811,1.0811,1.0811,1.0811,1.0811,1.0477,1.0098,0.9899,1.0001,0.978,1.0172,0.986,1.0635,1.1407,1.1714,1.1692,1.1989,1.2337,1.2324,1.2951,1.3655,1.3895,1.326,1.2307,1.184,1.1668,1.1457,1.2087,1.2901,1.3656,1.3724,1.3635,1.3846,1.4835,1.4857,1.4851,1.5488,1.5693,1.4011,1.301,1.2118,1.1344,1.0741,1.067
Czech Republic,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,21.145,27.92,28.37,29.153,28.785,26.541,27.145,31.698,32.281,34.569,38.598,38.035,32.739,28.209,25.7,23.957,22.596,20.294,17.072
Denmark,6.9071,6.9071,6.9071,6.9071,6.9071,6.9071,6.9071,6.9565,7.5,7.5,7.5,7.4169,6.9493,6.0495,6.0949,5.7462,6.045,6.0032,5.5146,5.261,5.6359,7.1234,8.3324,9.145,10.3566,10.5964,8.091,6.8403,6.7315,7.3102,6.1886,6.3965,6.0361,6.4839,6.3606,5.6024,5.7987,6.6045,6.7008,6.9762,8.0831,8.3228,7.8947,6.5877,5.9911,5.9969,5.9468,5.4437,5.0981
Finland,0.5382,0.5382,0.5382,0.5382,0.5382,0.5382,0.5382,0.58025,0.70638,0.70638,0.70638,0.70375,0.69736,0.64267,0.6347,0.61871,0.64995,0.6777,0.69249,0.65515,0.62735,0.72577,0.81074,0.93682,1.01081,1.04241,0.85263,0.73928,0.7035,0.72173,0.64307,0.68015,0.75339,0.96074,0.87853,0.73442,0.77258,0.87314,0.89881,0.93863,1.0854,1.11751,1.06255,0.88603,0.80537,0.80412,0.79714,0.73064,0.68268
France,0.75266,0.75266,0.75266,0.75266,0.75266,0.75266,0.75266,0.75266,0.75266,0.79185,0.84673,0.84496,0.769,0.67959,0.7339,0.65343,0.72855,0.74907,0.68802,0.64858,0.64419,0.8285,1.00191,1.16186,1.33227,1.36978,1.05588,0.91633,0.90812,0.97264,0.83013,0.86014,0.80704,0.86335,0.8464,0.76095,0.77986,0.8898,0.89938,0.93863,1.0854,1.11751,1.06255,0.88603,0.80537,0.80412,0.79714,0.73064,0.68268
Germany,2.14743,2.06221,2.04517,2.04517,2.04517,2.04517,2.04517,2.04517,2.04517,2.01619,1.87133,1.78481,1.63033,1.36648,1.3231,1.25793,1.28743,1.18731,1.027,0.93714,0.92936,1.15552,1.2407,1.30546,1.45511,1.50523,1.11026,0.91899,0.89795,0.96125,0.82611,0.84851,0.79846,0.84533,0.82972,0.73275,0.76938,0.88661,0.8997,0.93863,1.0854,1.11751,1.06255,0.88603,0.80537,0.80412,0.79714,0.73064,0.68268
Greece,0.08804,0.08804,0.08804,0.08804,0.08804,0.08804,0.08804,0.08804,0.08804,0.08804,0.08804,0.08804,0.08804,0.08694,0.08804,0.09406,0.10717,0.10811,0.10784,0.1087,0.12507,0.16261,0.19605,0.25844,0.33079,0.40534,0.4108,0.39745,0.41632,0.47665,0.46519,0.5349,0.55942,0.67278,0.71197,0.67986,0.70642,0.80134,0.86729,0.89698,1.07234,1.11751,1.06255,0.88603,0.80537,0.80412,0.79714,0.73064,0.68268
Hungary,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,60,60,60,59.82,55.26,48.97,46.75,43.97,41.58,40.96,37.91,35.58,32.53,34.31,36.63,42.67,48.04,50.12,45.83,46.97,50.41,59.07,63.21,74.74,78.99,91.93,105.16,125.68,152.65,186.79,214.4,237.15,282.18,286.49,257.89,224.31,202.75,199.58,210.39,183.63,172.11
Iceland,0.344,0.401,0.43,0.43,0.43,0.43,0.43,0.442,0.622,0.88,0.88,0.88,0.883,0.901,1,1.537,1.822,1.989,2.711,3.526,4.798,7.224,12.352,24.843,31.694,41.508,41.104,38.677,43.014,57.042,58.284,58.996,57.546,67.603,69.944,64.692,66.5,70.904,70.958,72.335,78.616,97.425,91.662,76.709,70.192,62.982,70.18,64.055,87.948
Ireland,0.45347,0.45347,0.45347,0.45347,0.45347,0.45347,0.45347,0.45977,0.52906,0.52906,0.52906,0.52176,0.50839,0.51827,0.54313,0.57397,0.70662,0.7279,0.66217,0.62038,0.61792,0.78889,0.89461,1.02173,1.1714,1.20068,0.94358,0.85443,0.83354,0.89585,0.76767,0.78888,0.74625,0.85993,0.84898,0.79198,0.79362,0.83757,0.8917,0.93863,1.0854,1.11751,1.06255,0.88603,0.80537,0.80412,0.79714,0.73064,0.68268
Italy,0.32226,0.32279,0.32279,0.32279,0.32279,0.32279,0.32279,0.32279,0.32279,0.32279,0.32279,0.32017,0.30121,0.30109,0.33587,0.33717,0.42987,0.45572,0.4383,0.4291,0.44232,0.58709,0.69851,0.78442,0.90739,0.98614,0.76994,0.66936,0.67223,0.70863,0.61877,0.64072,0.63649,0.81273,0.83276,0.84127,0.79687,0.87958,0.89668,0.93863,1.0854,1.11751,1.06255,0.88603,0.80537,0.80412,0.79714,0.73064,0.68268
Japan,360,360,360,360,360,360,360,360,360,360,360,349.33,303.17,271.7,292.08,296.79,296.55,268.51,210.44,219.14,226.74,220.54,249.08,237.51,237.52,238.54,168.52,144.64,128.15,137.96,144.79,134.71,126.65,111.2,102.21,94.06,108.78,120.99,130.91,113.91,107.77,121.53,125.39,115.93,108.19,110.22,116.3,117.75,103.36
Korea,..,..,..,..,..,..,271.3,270.5,276.7,288.2,310.6,347.2,392.9,398.3,404.5,484,484,484,484,484,607.4,681,731.1,775.8,806,870,881.5,822.6,731.5,671.5,707.8,733.4,780.7,802.7,803.4,771.3,804.5,951.3,1401.4,1188.8,1131,1291,1251.1,1191.6,1145.3,1024.1,954.8,929.3,1102.1
Luxembourg,1.23947,1.23947,1.23947,1.23947,1.23947,1.23947,1.23947,1.23947,1.23947,1.23947,1.23947,1.21145,1.09109,0.9662,0.96558,0.91173,0.957,0.88852,0.78067,0.72679,0.72488,0.92041,1.13264,1.26752,1.43243,1.47194,1.10739,0.92549,0.91146,0.9768,0.82841,0.84651,0.79697,0.85762,0.82936,0.73079,0.76752,0.88681,0.89982,0.93863,1.0854,1.11751,1.06255,0.88603,0.80537,0.80412,0.79714,0.73064,0.68268
Mexico,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.015,0.023,0.023,0.023,0.023,0.025,0.056,0.12,0.168,0.257,0.612,1.378,2.273,2.462,2.813,3.018,3.095,3.116,3.375,6.419,7.599,7.918,9.136,9.56,9.456,9.342,9.656,10.789,11.286,10.898,10.899,10.928,11.13
Netherlands,1.72436,1.6563,1.64268,1.64268,1.64268,1.64268,1.64268,1.64268,1.64268,1.64268,1.64268,1.58933,1.45641,1.26857,1.21993,1.14761,1.19977,1.11369,0.98179,0.91028,0.90217,1.13227,1.21169,1.29515,1.45604,1.50719,1.11177,0.91922,0.89693,0.96235,0.82631,0.84842,0.79796,0.84281,0.82588,0.72863,0.76503,0.88545,0.90018,0.93863,1.0854,1.11751,1.06255,0.88603,0.80537,0.80412,0.79714,0.73064,0.68268
New Zealand,0.7143,0.7155,0.7192,0.7192,0.7192,0.7192,0.7192,0.7337,0.8929,0.8929,0.8929,0.8806,0.8368,0.7368,0.7154,0.8323,1.0049,1.0303,0.9644,0.9785,1.0267,1.1528,1.3326,1.4968,1.764,2.0234,1.9132,1.6946,1.5264,1.6722,1.6762,1.7335,1.8618,1.8505,1.6865,1.5239,1.4549,1.5124,1.8683,1.8896,2.2012,2.3788,2.1622,1.7221,1.5087,1.4203,1.5421,1.3607,1.4227
Norway,7.1429,7.1429,7.1429,7.1429,7.1429,7.1429,7.1429,7.1429,7.1429,7.1429,7.1429,7.0418,6.5883,5.7658,5.5397,5.2269,5.4565,5.3235,5.2423,5.0641,4.9392,5.7395,6.454,7.2964,8.1615,8.5972,7.3947,6.7375,6.517,6.9045,6.2597,6.4829,6.2145,7.0941,7.0576,6.3352,6.4498,7.0734,7.5451,7.7992,8.8018,8.9917,7.9838,7.0802,6.7408,6.4425,6.4133,5.8617,5.64
Poland,..,..,..,..,..,..,0.0004,0.0004,0.0004,0.0004,0.0004,0.0004,0.0004,0.0003,0.0003,0.0003,0.0003,0.0003,..,0.004,0.0044,0.0051,0.0085,0.0092,0.0113,0.0147,0.0175,0.0265,0.0431,0.1439,0.95,1.0576,1.3626,1.8115,2.2723,2.425,2.6961,3.2793,3.4754,3.9671,4.3461,4.0939,4.08,3.8891,3.6576,3.2355,3.1032,2.768,2.4092
Portugal,0.1434,0.1434,0.1434,0.1434,0.1434,0.1434,0.1434,0.1434,0.1434,0.1434,0.1434,0.14122,0.13494,0.12228,0.12673,0.12746,0.15078,0.19092,0.21916,0.24403,0.24971,0.30699,0.39641,0.55257,0.73019,0.84993,0.74614,0.70272,0.71804,0.7854,0.71106,0.72067,0.67337,0.80207,0.82797,0.75371,0.76937,0.87445,0.89835,0.93863,1.0854,1.11751,1.06255,0.88603,0.80537,0.80412,0.79714,0.73064,0.68268
Slovak Republic,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,1.0214,1.0637,0.9863,1.0175,1.1159,1.1695,1.373,1.5281,1.6051,1.5046,1.2206,1.0707,1.0296,0.9858,0.8197,0.7091
Spain,0.36061,0.36061,0.36061,0.36061,0.36061,0.36061,0.36061,0.37063,0.42071,0.42071,0.42071,0.41752,0.38628,0.35015,0.3467,0.34502,0.4021,0.45654,0.46078,0.40343,0.43094,0.55487,0.66027,0.86203,0.96619,1.02199,0.84171,0.74212,0.7001,0.71147,0.61264,0.62452,0.61531,0.76485,0.8051,0.7494,0.76125,0.87997,0.89788,0.93863,1.0854,1.11751,1.06255,0.88603,0.80537,0.80412,0.79714,0.73064,0.68268
Sweden,5.1732,5.1732,5.1732,5.1732,5.1732,5.1732,5.1732,5.1732,5.1732,5.1732,5.1732,5.1168,4.7624,4.3673,4.4394,4.1522,4.3559,4.4816,4.5185,4.2871,4.2296,5.0634,6.2826,7.6671,8.2718,8.6039,7.1236,6.3404,6.1272,6.4469,5.9188,6.0475,5.8238,7.7834,7.716,7.1333,6.706,7.6349,7.9499,8.2624,9.1622,10.3291,9.7371,8.0863,7.3489,7.4731,7.3783,6.7588,6.5911
Switzerland,4.373,4.373,4.373,4.373,4.373,4.373,4.373,4.373,4.373,4.373,4.373,4.1342,3.8193,3.1648,2.9793,2.5813,2.4996,2.4035,1.788,1.6627,1.6757,1.9642,2.0303,2.0991,2.3497,2.4571,1.7989,1.4912,1.4633,1.6359,1.3892,1.434,1.4062,1.4776,1.3677,1.1825,1.236,1.4513,1.4498,1.5022,1.6888,1.6876,1.5586,1.3467,1.2435,1.2452,1.2538,1.2004,1.0831
Turkey,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,0.0001,0.0001,0.0002,0.0002,0.0004,0.0005,0.0007,0.0009,0.0014,0.0021,0.0026,0.0042,0.0069,0.011,0.0296,0.0458,0.0814,0.1519,0.2607,0.4188,0.6252,1.2256,1.5072,1.5009,1.4255,1.3436,1.4285,1.3029,1.3015
United Kingdom,0.35714,0.35714,0.35714,0.35714,0.35714,0.35714,0.35714,0.3621,0.41667,0.41667,0.41667,0.41092,0.40039,0.40817,0.42776,0.45204,0.55651,0.57327,0.52151,0.47218,0.4303,0.49764,0.57245,0.65973,0.75181,0.77925,0.6822,0.61193,0.56217,0.61117,0.56318,0.56702,0.56977,0.66676,0.65343,0.63367,0.64096,0.61084,0.60382,0.61806,0.66093,0.69466,0.66722,0.61247,0.54618,0.55,0.54349,0.49977,0.54397
United States,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
Euro area,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,0.76452,0.78756,0.8818,0.89199,0.93863,1.0854,1.11751,1.06255,0.88603,0.80537,0.80412,0.79714,0.73064,0.68268
Brazil,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0002,0.0005,0.0007,0.0009,0.001,0.0013,0.0016,0.0018,0.002,0.0023,0.0024,0.0026,0.0031,0.0041,0.0055,0.007,0.0104,0.0203,0.0359,0.0693,0.2227,0.7131,2.3925,5.2694,15.137,79.6677,-,-,0.0001,0.0016,0.0322,0.6393,0.9177,1.0051,1.078,1.1605,1.8139,1.8294,2.3496,2.9204,3.0775,2.9251,2.4344,2.1753,1.9471,1.8338
Chile,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,396.77,412.27,419.3,460.29,508.78,539.59,634.94,688.94,691.4,609.53,559.77,530.28,522.46,522.46
China,2.462,2.462,2.462,2.462,2.462,2.462,2.462,2.462,2.462,2.462,2.462,2.462,2.245,1.989,1.961,1.86,1.941,1.858,1.684,1.555,1.498,1.705,1.893,1.976,2.32,2.937,3.453,3.722,3.722,3.765,4.783,5.323,5.515,5.762,8.619,8.351,8.314,8.29,8.279,8.278,8.279,8.277,8.277,8.277,8.277,8.194,7.973,7.608,6.949
Estonia,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,13.223,12.991,11.465,12.038,13.882,14.075,14.678,16.969,17.478,16.612,13.856,12.596,12.584,12.466,11.434,10.694
India,4.77,4.78,4.77,4.78,4.79,4.79,6.3,7.56,7.58,7.59,7.57,7.52,7.59,7.74,8.1,8.38,8.96,8.74,8.19,8.13,7.86,8.66,9.46,10.1,11.36,12.37,12.61,12.96,13.92,16.23,17.5,22.74,25.92,30.49,31.37,32.43,35.43,36.31,41.26,43.06,44.94,47.19,48.61,46.58,45.32,44.1,45.31,41.35,43.51
Indonesia,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,150,296,326,363,392,415,415,415,415,415,415,442,623,627,632,661,909,1026,1111,1283,1644,1686,1770,1843,1950,2030,2087,2161,2249,2342,2909,10014,7855,8422,10261,9311,8577,8939,9705,9159,9141,9699
Israel 1,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,3.0113,3.1917,3.4494,3.8001,4.1397,4.0773,4.2057,4.7378,4.5541,4.482,4.4877,4.4558,4.1081,3.588
Russian Federation,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,0.992,2.191,4.559,5.121,5.785,9.705,24.62,28.129,29.169,31.349,30.692,28.814,28.284,27.191,25.581,24.853
Slovenia,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,..,0.11505,0.3392,0.47255,0.53751,0.49457,0.56486,0.66637,0.69326,0.75851,0.92913,1.01297,1.00254,0.86427,0.80279,0.80414,0.79715,0.73064,0.68268
South Africa,0.713,0.715,0.713,0.715,0.717,0.716,0.717,0.717,0.717,0.718,0.716,0.712,0.773,0.694,0.679,0.74,0.87,0.87,0.87,0.842,0.779,0.878,1.086,1.114,1.475,2.229,2.285,2.036,2.273,2.623,2.587,2.761,2.852,3.268,3.551,3.627,4.299,4.608,5.528,6.109,6.94,8.609,10.541,7.565,6.46,6.359,6.772,7.045,8.261

```
public static ArrayList<String> getYears() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("exchangerates.csv");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    ArrayList<String> years = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = br.readLine();
    String year = "";
    for(int i = 1; i < line.length(); i++) {
        if(line.charAt(i) != ',' && i != line.length()-1) {
            year = year + line.charAt(i);
        }
        else if(i == line.length()-1) {
            year = year + line.charAt(i);
            years.add(year);
        }
        else {
            years.add(year);
            year = "";
        }
    }
    br.close();
    return years;
}

public static LinkedHashMap<String,LinkedHashMap<String,Double>> getExchangeRates() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("exchangerates.csv");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    //burn first line
    br.readLine();

    LinkedHashMap<String,LinkedHashMap<String,Double>> exchangeRatesTable = new LinkedHashMap<String,LinkedHashMap<String,Double>>();

    String line = null;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String country = "";
        int index = 0;
        while(line.charAt(index) != ',') {
            country = country + line.charAt(index);
            index++;
        }
        index++; //skip comma
        LinkedHashMap<String,Double> yearlyRateMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,Double>();
        for(String year : getYears()) {
            String rateString = "";
            for(int k = index; k < line.length(); k++) {
                if(line.charAt(k) != ',' && k != line.length()-1) {
                    rateString = rateString + line.charAt(k);
                    index++;
                }
                else if(k == line.length()-1) {
                    rateString = rateString + line.charAt(k);
                    index++;
                    if(!rateString.equals("..")) {
                        Double exchangeRate = new Double(rateString);
                        yearlyRateMap.put(year, exchangeRate);
                    }
                    else {
                        index++;
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    if(!rateString.equals("..") && !rateString.equals("-")) {
                        index++;
                        Double exchangeRate = new Double(rateString);
                        yearlyRateMap.put(year, exchangeRate);

                    }
                    else {
                        index++;
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        exchangeRatesTable.put(country, yearlyRateMap);
    }

    br.close();

    return exchangeRatesTable;
}
```

Comment: Could the spaces in your CSV be funny non-breakable spaces, i.e. not the same character as you're using in your lookup?

Comment: Why not change your code to use `String.split()` instead of parsing character by character?

Comment: @Dan McNamara, what's the problem with code. Its' working fine.

Comment: While printing getExchangeRates().get("New Zealand") also gives correct output not null.

Comment: Just compiled your code: It works. Also: Czech Republic contains rates for the years 1990, 1991 and so on while the other countries only have rates for 1960 and so on. Not to mention, that the CSV snippet you provided does not contain Czech Republic at all. And last, but not least, you seem to read the years for each line of data over and over again. Maybe you would like to update your question?! It might help me help you help us all.

Comment: Included entire csv document. Didn't know what would be best way of sharing that. Maybe it is a case like beny23 mentioned. I am working on a mac and maybe the csv file white spaces are encoded in a windows-friendly way?

Comment: That actually was the problem. Ctrl-F for a space character or a \s regex both returned nothing.